# Creating 3D captcha with different fonts

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm interested in making 3D captchas and I have it working with a single font as seen below:

```
import string
from matplotlib.font_manager import findSystemFonts
import random
from PIL import ImageFont, Image, ImageDraw

def rand_font(fonts=[], fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf', font_encoding='', min_size=24, max_size=36):
    if fonts == []:
        fonts = findSystemFonts(fontpaths, fontext)
    requested_font = fonts[random.randint(0, len(fonts)-1)]
    font_size = random.randint(min_size, max_size)
    return ImageFont.truetype(requested_font, font_size, encoding=font_encoding)

def create_captcha(text):
    def _rand_color():
        colors = ['red', 'orange', 'white', 'purple', 'green', 'yellow']
        return colors[random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)]

    width = random.randint(400, 700)
    height = random.randint(150, 200)
    angle = angle if angle else uniform(-20, 20)


    font = rand_font()

    text_width, text_height = font.getsize(text)

    img = Image.new("L", (text_width * 3, text_height * 3), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    draw.text((text_width, text_height), text, font=font)

    fig = pylab.figure(figsize=(width/100.0, height/100.0), dpi=4000)
    axes = Axes3D(fig)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(range(img.size[0]), range(img.size[1]))
    Z = 1 - numpy.asarray(img) / 255


    func = Axes3D.plot_surface if random.randint(0,1) == 0 else Axes3D.plot_wireframe

    func(axes, X, -Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, color=_rand_color())

    axes.set_zlim((-3, 3))
    axes.set_xlim((text_width * 1.1, text_width * 1.9))
    axes.set_ylim((-text_height * 1.9, -text_height* 1.1))
    axes.set_axis_off()
    axes.view_init(elev=60, azim=-90)
```

And that's good and all, it can make me create things like this:
http://puu.sh/dfxcW/d9fc3f5c4e.jpg and
http://puu.sh/dft1a/1d35f5c99a.png

What I would like to do though is create a captcha that uses a different font and size for each character and offset the `y` by a little for each character.

Since it plots it based off a `numpy` array I've tried looping through each character in the text like so:

```
prev_x = 0
x = []
y = []
z = []
for character in text:
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(range(prev_x, prev_x + img.size[0]), range(img.size[1]))
    for v in X.tolist():
        x.append(v)
    for v in Y.tolist():
        y.append(v)
    # same for z
prev_x += 40 # trying to offset the characters by an x value so they dont overlap
x = numpy.array(x)
# same for y and z to convert back to numpy array
Axes3D.plot_wireframe(x, -y, z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
```

This results in `shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 1.` which confuses me because I thought the dimensions would be the exact same since I'm doing the same call on each one. I'm new to numpy and 3D stuff so if anyone has suggestions please let me know!

Comment: Why don't you just double check the dimensions?  You've skipped some code here so it can't be accurately debugged.

Comment: I've checked the dimensions, they don't match. I haven't skipped code, I provided everything. The 2nd part can easily be copy-pastad into the first part

Comment: You most certainly have skipped code - in order to get this to work I had to add a ton of imports and replace your lines that say "# same for z", and whatnot.  Also your `Axes3D.plot_wireframe()` call should be `axes.plot_wireframe()`, so unless you didn't actually copy and paste your real code into the question, something else is completely messed up.  Given that your question title does not match your question content, I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: It was typed here, hence why I wrote `# same for z`. I'm sorry to have inconvenienced you by having you import modules. `Axes3D.plot_wireframe` was supposed to be called with `axes` acting as `self`. The reason can be seen in the first example where I assign it the method and call it later. The question is how do I implement this. My code does not work for different fonts as I have stated, instead I have provided enough context for a decent developer to understand what I was trying to do. If you would like me to copy/paste everything I can but the result will do nothing since it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually after the changes I mentioned I got it to work just fine, with random fonts and colors. I'll post it when I get back to an actual computer.

Comment: Random fonts and colors for each character? I look forward to see how you solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's definitely a lot of cool factor in how you started this, and it was mostly there; here's what mods I made to get random fonts and possibly colors on a per-character basis. I did change some of the sizing to better fit my screen.

```
from matplotlib.font_manager import findSystemFonts
import random
from PIL import ImageFont, Image, ImageDraw
import numpy
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rand_font(fonts=[], fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf', font_encoding='', min_size=24, max_size=36):
    if fonts == []:
        fonts = findSystemFonts(fontpaths, fontext)
    requested_font = fonts[random.randint(0, len(fonts)-1)]
    font_size = random.randint(min_size, max_size)
    return ImageFont.truetype(requested_font, font_size, encoding=font_encoding)

def create_captcha(text):
    def _rand_color():
        colors = ['red', 'orange', 'purple', 'green', 'yellow']
        return colors[random.randint(0, len(colors)-1)]

    # First font just gets the general offsets
    font = rand_font()
    text_width, text_height = font.getsize(text)

    # Dont draw text here first
    img = Image.new("L", (text_width * 3, text_height * 3), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    axes = Axes3D(fig)

    # Do this way if you want random fonts AND colors
    #=================
    prev_x = 0
    for character in text:
        cfont = rand_font()
        char_wid, char_height = cfont.getsize(character)
        draw.text((prev_x+text_width, text_height), character, font=cfont)

        X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(range(prev_x+text_width, prev_x+text_width+char_wid),
                              range(text_height, text_height+char_height))
        Z = 1 - numpy.asarray(img.crop((prev_x+text_width, text_height,
                                        prev_x+text_width+char_wid,
                                        text_height+char_height))) / 255
        axes.plot_wireframe(X, -Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, color=_rand_color())

        prev_x += char_wid # trying to offset the characters by an x value so they dont overlap
    #=================

    # Do this way if you want just random fonts on each letter all one color
    #=================
    prev_x = 0
    for character in text:
        cfont = rand_font()
        char_wid, char_height = cfont.getsize(character)
        draw.text((prev_x+text_width, text_height), character, font=cfont)

        prev_x += char_wid # trying to offset the characters by an x value so they dont overlap

    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(range(img.size[0]), range(img.size[1]))
    Z = 1 - numpy.asarray(img) / 255
    axes.plot_wireframe(X, -Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, color=_rand_color())
    #=================

    axes.set_zlim((-3, 3))
    axes.set_xlim((text_width * 1.1, text_width * 1.9))
    axes.set_ylim((-text_height * 1.9, -text_height* 1.1))
    axes.set_axis_off()
    axes.view_init(elev=60, azim=-90)
    plt.show()

create_captcha('TEST')
```

The multi-font single color version looks something like this:
[image: test image all one color]

and the multi-font multi-color version looks like this:
[image: test image multiple colors]

which can probably be made to look nicer if you make it a surface and change the view angle/height to avoid the background... perhaps like this:
[image: test image multiple colors with raised surface]

It should be a starting point, at least!